# Minecraft: /blockdata within a radius

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make the /blockdata command work on blocks within a radius of a mob. Basically, I am trying to edit all signs around a zombie named "Empty_Child" to read:

Mummy?
Are you my
mummy?

This is the command I am using so far, but it only works on the block that the zombie is standing in: /execute @e[name=Empty_Child] ~ ~ ~ /blockdata ~ ~ ~ {Text1:"{"text":"Mummy?"}",Text2:"{"text":"Are you my"}",Text3:"{"text":"mummy?"}"}

Comment: NOOO! WHY WOULD YOU DO THAT?!? And it's even a great, spooky way to implement it in Minecraft, good job. But still: AAAAAHHH!!!

Comment: @Fabian Thanks! I gave the zombies gas masks (using custom heads) and they even infect villagers! I just need to find a way to get the sign editing working!

Comment: I just remembered that it's actually possible in 1.13, because you can specify a data tag for the block that you want to replace. Remember me again once 1.13 is (or at least somewhat usable snapshots are) out to write another answer.

Comment: Btw, SethBling once made a "weeping angels" concept in Minecraft, which you could now even improve with elytra.

Comment: I actually attempted at making Weeping Angels (with Elytra, too) some time ago using Sethbling's concept, but the commands became incompatible with the latest version of Minecraft. :/    All I have for Weeping Angels so far is a stray named "Weeping_Angel" wearing Elytra...

Comment: The facing direction changed a few times since then, it's even different between 1.12.2 and the latest snapshot. Just experiment a bit how it behaves now and it should still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to use `/blockdata` in a radius.

I once made a command system to do something similar, but that's way too much effort and especially too much to process (I get about 5tps with it on a relatively good PC).

So I would recommend you to just execute the command multiple times, each with different relative coordinates, that should be the easiest solution for your case.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how to get those relative coordinates working. I tried adding a 1 after the ~ in a separate command block, but it failed to make a difference.

Comment: That's very weird, it should. Can you copy the exact commands from the command history (don't type here, copy to be extra sure) and link screenshots?

Comment: /blockdata ~1 ~1 ~1 {Text1:"{\"text\":\"Mummy?\"}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"Are you my\"}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"mummy?\"}"}

minecraft minecraft-commands

Comment: No, I mean from in the game. You obviously copied the command from here, because you accidentally copied the tags.

Comment: I deleted the command block before you asked. Sorry :P

Comment: Then try again. Who knows, maybe it works when you try again?

Comment: Nope. Not working. It just says "Failed to execute command as (insert the command here) as Empty_Child" while the other one (without the 1s after the ~) works fine.

Comment: Can you copy the exact commands (the working one and the not working one) from the command blocks now?

Comment: Working: /execute @e[name=Empty_Child] ~ ~ ~ /blockdata ~ ~ ~ {Text1:"{\"text\":\"Mummy?\"}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"Are you my\"}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"mummy?\"}"} ---------------------- Not working: /execute @e[name=Empty_Child] ~ ~ ~ /blockdata ~1 ~1 ~1 {Text1:"{\"text\":\"Mummy?\"}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"Are you my\"}",Text3:"{\"text\":\"mummy?\"}"}

Comment: Both shouldn't be working. Leave out the second splash. If it's in a command block, leave out all (regular) slashes.

Comment: Does `execute @e[...] ~1 ~1 ~1 blockdata ~ ~ ~` work?

Comment: Yes, I did put it into the execute part, that was intentional and exactly my point. Did you try it?

Comment: No, you don't have to give up. You just have to execute the command a few times. I just tested it: `/blockdata ~ ~ ~1 {Text1:"{\"text\":\"b\"}"}` works perfectly fine if one block in positive z direction there's a sign, also with `execute @p ~ ~ ~ ` in front of it. But be careful: If the text on the sign doesn't change (in this case if you try to overwrite "b" with "b"), it looks like the command failed.